# ms Access: Looping through array of DAO recordsets results in element always being missing

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, ms-access

I have some vba code that 'attempts' to loop through an array of DAO recordsets. When running the loop, I get a runtime error 'Oject required' at `rst.MoveFirst`. It seems that rst is not properly initialized but I'm not sure how to fix it. Maybe looping through an array of recordsets isnt even possible in this way I have never tried it before. The code runs from a custom class module. There is a bunch more code in the module but most of the important stuff I post below. A couple things I tried:

*Set rst to a new recordset instance manually:*

```
Set rst = New DAO.Recordset
```

*Declaring the array outside the loop:*

```
Set recordsets = Array(rstRechenwerte, rstZwischenwerte, rstZutaten)

' Loop through each recordset and insert data into Excel file
For Each rst In recordsets
```

*Setting rst to an open recordset right before `rst.MoveFirst`:*

```
For Each rst In Array(rstRechenwerte, rstZwischenwerte, rstZutaten)
    Set rst = rst.OpenRecordset()
    rst.MoveFirst
```

The three recordsets in the array are properly initialized, set and are not Nothing. I had previously written the code for each of the three recordsets seperately and it works that way. I am aware that I need to change the variable name XLColumn, but thats not really an issue atm. Its probably something bassic but I couldn't figure it out for a while now so I thought I'd just ask.

I am using the following libraries for which references are properly set:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object
  Library
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

*My version of Access:*

```
Microsoft® Access® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20002) 32 Bit
```

***The code:***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim rsRes As DAO.Recordset     'rs of temp table (Output)
Dim rsZwi As DAO.Recordset     'rs of temp table (Zwischenwerte)
Dim rsRec As DAO.Recordset     'rs clone of subform Rechenwerte
Dim Recordset As Recordset
Dim rstRechenwerte As DAO.Recordset 'rs of tblRechenwerte
Dim rstZwischenwerte As DAO.Recordset   'rs of tblZwischenwerte
Dim rstZutaten As DAO.Recordset     'rs of tblZutaten
Dim RezeptID As Integer     'Current form active RezeptID
Dim RechengruppeID As Integer       'Current Form active RechengruppeID
Dim xlColumn As String  'Excel Column of Zutaten
Dim xlLastRow As Long   'Excel last row number after insertion
Dim xlColumn2 As String 'Excel Column one to the right of Zutaten
Dim k As Integer
Dim Export As Boolean   'Export the Excel File
Dim ExclExportPath As String    'Export location as string

Sub Calculate()
'***************************************************************************
'Purpose: Calculate a recipe based on Rechenwerte,
     'save them temporarily and display them on a form.
'Inputs: None
'***************************************************************************

'***********************************************************************
' Preparations
'***********************************************************************

'Disable user input
Call mdlMiscFunctions.DisableKeyboardMouse(True)

'Clear temporary data tables for Results and Zwischenwerte
If Not rsRes.EOF Then Call ClearTableOnClose("tblTempResults")
If Not rsZwi.EOF Then Call ClearTableOnClose("tblTempZwischenwerte")

'Prevent prompt to save changes to excel
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Visible = False

'***********************************************************************
' Insert Data into Excel File
'***********************************************************************


Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim xlCell As String
Dim xlFormula As String
Dim xlColumn As String

' Loop through each recordset and insert data into Excel file
For Each rst In Array(rstRechenwerte, rstZwischenwerte, rstZutaten)
    rst.MoveFirst
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        Do Until rst.EOF
            xlCell = rst!xlCell
            xlSheet.Range(xlCell).Value = rst.Fields(1)
            If rst.Fields.Count > 2 Then
                xlFormula = rst!xlFormula
                xlSheet.Range(xlCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = xlFormula
                xlSheet.Range(xlCell).Offset(0, 1).Value = xlSheet.Range(xlCell).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
                xlSheet.Range(xlCell).Offset(0, 1).Value = rst.Fields(2)
            End If
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        Select Case rst.Name
            Case "rstRechenwerte"
                MsgBox "Error: Keine Rechenwerte vorhanden!", vbCritical
            Case "rstZwischenwerte"
                MsgBox "Error: Keine Zwischenwerte vorhanden!", vbCritical
            Case "rstZutaten"
                MsgBox "Error: Keine Zutaten vorhanden!", vbCritical
        End Select
    End If
Next rst
```

***Class initialization is the following:***

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'***************************************************************************
'Purpose: Sub for initializing class variables
'Inputs: None
'***************************************************************************

'Values for variables 1 (Neccesary for recordsets)
RezeptID = Forms.frmCalcBatch.RezeptID  'RezeptID on current form
RechengruppeID = Forms.frmCalcBatch.RechengruppeID  'Rechengruppe on Current Form
'Initialize Objects
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Tabelle1") 'Set xlSheet to the first sheet in the workbook
Set rsRes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempResults", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsZwi = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempZwischenwerte", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsRec = Forms.frmCalcBatch.frmSubRechenwerteBox.Form.Recordset.Clone    'rs clone of Rechenwerte subform
Set rstRechenwerte = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Rechenwert, WertBezeichnung, XLCell FROM tblRechenwerte WHERE RechengruppeID = " & RechengruppeID)
Set rstZwischenwerte = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ZWBezeichnung, XLFormula, XLCell FROM tblZwischenwerte WHERE RezeptID = " & RezeptID)
Set rstZutaten = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Zutat, XLFormula, XLCell FROM tblZutaten WHERE RezeptID = " & RezeptID)
'Values for Variables 2 (recordsets neccesary for variables)
xlColumn2 = Split(rstZutaten!xlCell, "1")(0)    'extract excel column denominator for Zutaten
xlColumn2 = Chr(Asc(xlColumn2) + 1)     'Move one column to the right using Asc (A->B etc.)

'Settings:
If Forms.frmCalcBatch.cbExport = True Then
    Export = True
    ExclExportPath = GetExportPath
Else
    Export = False
    ExclExportPath = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `New` up a `DAO.Recordset`, the code will not even compile.

To loop through an array of recordsets, each recordset must initialized before it is added to the array.

For example:

```
Dim r1 As DAO.Recordset, r2 As DAO.Recordset, r3 As DAO.Recordset

Set r1 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("YourTableOrQueryName")
Set r2 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("YourTableOrQueryName")
Set r3 = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("YourTableOrQueryName")
```

Put the recordsets now in the array.

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array(r1, r2, r3)
```

To loop, you need to use a `For` loop and either access the recordset from the array directly, or declare another recordset variable to hold the iterating recordset.

Through an iterator variable:

```
Dim r As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Set r = arr(i)
    If Not r.EOF Then
        r.MoveFirst
        Debug.Print r.RecordCount
    End If
Next i
```

Access it directly from the array:

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Not arr(i).EOF Then
        arr(i).MoveFirst
        Debug.Print arr(i).RecordCount
    End If
Next i
```

Though I fail to see why you need to have 3 recordsets in memory at the same time. Personally, I would offload the work that needs to be done in the loop to a separate function and pass the recordset as parameter. The function itself would return a success/failed status, so you can take the appropriate action based on the result.

Another approach would be to store the source names in the array, and create the recordset on demand during the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The new DAO thing was just something i tried when troubleshooting. Obviously it didnt improve anything but its not the reason I received the error in the first place. Isn't looping through the array using the iterator pretty much what I did? I just used `for each` instead of `for`. The three recordsets in the array are set in the `Class_Initialize` sub. I declared `rst` as a DAO recordset and used it as the iterator variable.

Comment: `New DAO.Recordset` is an *invalid* statement and the code does not compile - not sure how you managed to run the code with this statement in it. Also, you cannot iterate everything with a `For Each` since the foreach statement returns an `IUnknown` which the recorsdet is not. You could if you wrote a custom collection implementing the `Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown`.

Comment: sry, maybe I wasn't clear. I did not have `New DAO.Recordset` in the original code. I just tried adding it during troubleshooting. It does not compile with it there, you're right about that. I romoved it after that. Didnt know about recordsets not working with IUnknown. Using `For` fixes the issue.